# I suspect an author of a paper I'm reading was listed improperly - what to do?

Tags: authorship

I was reading a paper. And the list of authors looks suspicious. Three of the authors are at some random place I haven't heard of and the fourth author is a well-known professor at a top university. The paper itself is not very good.

I suspect the well-known author may have been listed to improve the paper's chances of acceptance. (Most reviews in my field are only single blind.)
Of course, it is possible that nothing is wrong - I can't be sure.

Is there anything I can or should do?

Comment: Are you suggesting that the impressive-sounding author was listed without his/her consent? Or that he/she agreed to be listed despite not having contributed anything to help some "random" researchers get their paper accepted?

Comment: You might check the well-known professor's web site to see whether the paper is mentioned there.

Comment: If you're really suspicious, you could simply e-mail the well-known professor, attach the paper, and ask him about it. If you're worried about offending him, you could mask it by asking him a genuine question about the paper.

Comment: @SteveHeim If the paper is bad, how do you ask a genuine question about it?

Comment: Without reading the paper, I don't know. Asking for clarifications on something perhaps? Why such-and-such statement is made?

Comment: Along similar lines to @AndreasBlass's suggestion, you could see if any of the well-known professor's other papers cite this one.

Comment: If the paper is correct from mathematical/theoretical point of view there is no problem to be addressed. Concerning the case of authorship is professor's business, presuming he has agreed with it and is aware. I know many professors who submit small papers to low quality journals simply because of the grant request, because the grant is given only and only if a number of papers is the output.

Answer (score 1):

**Can?** Yes - the comments already give you some hints: Look at the prof's website, try asking him a question about the paper.

**Should?** Probably not. If there is really something going on, then it would the business of the professor, not yours. If you proceed as above and ask him something, and there is really something fishy, he can decide by himself if something needs to be done.